# RazorPage .NET 5 how to customize localization provider (.resx to database)

Tags: localization, razor-pages, .net-5, asp.net5

I am in the process of migrating an ASP.NET Webform .net 4.8 to RazorPage .Net5.

In my asp.net webform website, I had deported the translation part to the database instead of a .resx file.

I had inherited from the following classes: ResourceProviderFactory, IResourceProvider and ExpressionBuilder

```xml
<expressionBuilders>
   <remove expressionPrefix="Resources" />
   <!-- For Translator -->
   <add expressionPrefix="Resources" type="WebCore.Resource.SqlExpressionBuilder" />
</expressionBuilders>
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" resourceProviderFactoryType="WebCore.Resource.SqlProviderFactory" />
```

which allowed to keep the asp.net syntax

```html
<meta name="description" content="<%= GetLocalResourceObject("MetaDescription") %>" />
```

With razop pages you have to use

```html
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@Localizer["MyDescription"]
```

And configure service

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddViewLocalization();
}
```

How to change the default behavior of the localization service, from which class should you inherit and how to inject this new class so that the resources are loaded with this new DB provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the solution, here's how.

Create classes that implement IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizerFactory

In the Startup of the site

Add :

```cs
services.AddRazorPages().AddViewLocalization();

services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, SqlStringLocalizerFactory>();
```

into razor page use

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<h1>@Localizer["Title"]</h1>
```

if you want to get the values in your c # code you can inject an **IStringLocalizer** but if your resource is in html you must use **IHtmlLocalizer**